# Show the space of linear maps from finite dimentional space to infinite dimentional space is infinite dimentional

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and $W$ is infinite dimensional, then prove that the set of linear transformations from $V$ to $W$ is infinite dimentional

Comment: Shoot... even the set of maps from a one dimensional space to an infinite dimensional space is infinite dimensional... consider for example $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^\Bbb N$ and the collection of linearly independent maps $T_n(x)=(0,0,\dots,0,x,0,\dots)$ which map the number $x$ to the sequence numbers whose only nonzero entry is the $n$'th entry which is set equal to $x$.  The same idea can be applied to your general scenario with careful enough wording.

Comment: Hello! I see you already have some down-votes, but that no one cared to comment on why. You will have more success if you also explain what work you have done already. If you don't even know where to begin, which is common enough for me, you can tell us what definitions you know that might reveal how we can fill you knowledge gaps. Cheers!